# Read command option not available on older OS Linux .. What other command to allow default value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, input

We have over 500 plus linux hosts with variation of OS running ; 
The read commands to prompt users with a default input is not working on soem and works on others.

Is there a command that I can use in all these varied OS to allow default input

```
2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64  = Works


2.6.18-348.6.1.el5   = Does not work
```

There is NO  I option in the older reads. 
read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]

I basically want to give user option to overwrite the default value at prompt but if they don't I want to take the default value

```
example:

read -e -p "Enter Your Name:" -i "Allesandra" N
```

Can you all offer an alternative? 
Thanks

Comment: `read` is a shell built-in. It has nothing to do with the kernel.

Comment: If you have versions of `bash` older than 4.0 that you have to deal with then you can't use `-i` and you have to present the default in the prompt or on a line before the prompt and manually check for blank and replace it with the default afterward.

Comment: Thx both .. Yes you both are right .. I realize that -- I was wondering if there is any other way to code so it does not matetr which one I use?

Comment: You could write your own `read` replacement function which tests the builtin for `-i` support and works around it if you want but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is exactly why the POSIX standard exists; stick with it. Depending on the OS, `bash` may not even be the default shell.

```
printf 'Enter Your Name, or leave blank for default:\n'
printf '(Allesandra): '
read name && [ -n "$name" ] || name=Allesandra
```

Answer (score 1):

One underutilized feature in most shells is the ability to provide a default value for a variable if it is unset.

```
read -e -p "Enter Your Name:" N
: ${N:=default}
```

However, I would expect if you have `read ... -i ...` on a version that doesn't support `-i` you're going to get an error.

IHTH